# CSS: specificity not behaving for js injected stylesheets?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, responsive-design

As part of a mobile-first build, i am loading the 'desktop' css dynamically in a blocking fashion

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 640px)");
    if(mq.matches){
        var stylesheet = document.createElement('link');
        stylesheet.href = '<?php echo $src ?>';
        stylesheet.rel = 'stylesheet';
        stylesheet.type = 'text/css';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(stylesheet);
    }
</script>
```

However, webkit and ff give more power to the css loaded pre-injection.

[image]

Even if `SetTimeout` 3 seconds before loading mboxes.css, the browsers still favour the css rules that were not injected.

How can i get the css specificity rules to behave?

Comment: You could empower the selector you want to override by giving it a greater specificity through selector calculation, maybe `div.mbox p` or whatnot. Why are you trying to rely strictly on page load? I don't think when it loads is important, but *where*, as in, which is closer to the element. So another issue could be where it's being appended to your `head[0]`, too.

Comment: Context could be important here. Could you provide a complete reduced test case? Your example code is missing the stylesheets and the HTML that pulls them into the page. A live demo would be helpful.

Comment: The selectors used are as shown in the Chrome inspector. `.main_content p` and `.mbox p`. The moboxes.css file is loaded and parsed **after** event_core.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, worked this out.

For the CSS to behave "normally" it needs to be injected into the `<body>` not the `<head>`.

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(stylesheet);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the ordering of the CSS that is being loaded, it is loading the values of event_core as the master so to override this you have 2 easy options without rewriting the js.

You can execute the Javascript before the event_core.css or after depending what you have at the moment.

Or the easiest way but depends realistically how much CSS you have in mboxes.css would to use !important within the CSS which will tell the browsers these are most important and become the new master.

For example

```
.mob p {
color:white!important;
}
```

Or make the edit the rules so that both are the same, for example .content > .mbox p

Answer (score -1):

The problem has nothing to do with the way the css files is loaded and more to do with the rules of css precedence. Basically, the more specific the selector, the higher priority the rule has. In your case both selectors are the same priority (class and element selector), <strike>so some browsers will choose one, other the other</strike> the last loaded should override the first, but it's not something I would count on.

The fix is to make the rules in mboxes.css more specific like `.mbox.main_content p`.

A second option is to add `!important` after each style like (like `color: white !important`), but I would recommend against that.

Comment: "so some browsers will choose one, other the other" — They shouldn't do. The rules for which selector to choose are very clear, if they are of equal specificity then the last one wins (or rather, gets applied over the top of the previous)

Comment: `!important` always makes me itchy.

Comment: `!important` is a sledgehammer that you can only use once. You can't double `!important` things. It is usually the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I'm pretty certain specificity battles aren't the answer.